# Table with divs as display: table and display:table-cell doesn't show properly

Tags: html-table, css-tables

I'm trying to make a table with divs but it won't show properly. This is what I'm getting: [the second cell isn't aligned with the first one](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B8Vo1.png). I tried everything but I just couldn't make it work.

Here's my code:

```
<div style="display: table; width:100%">
    <div style="display: table-cell;">
        <img src="" style="width:400px;">                                    
    </div>  
    <div style="display: table-cell;">
        Lorem ipsum dolor            
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<div style="display: table; width:100%">
    <div style="display: table-cell;">
        <img src="" style="width:400px;">                                    
    </div>  
    <div style="display: table-cell; vertical-align: top;">
        Lorem ipsum dolor            
    </div>
</div>
```

In second div use "vertical-align: top;" property.